# Iterator for a vector<vector<pair<long long,long long> > >

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

I am using `vector<vector<pair<long long,long long>>> ar;`
now i want to use its iterator and when i am declaring it as `vector<vector<pair<long long,long long> > > :: iterator i;`
its showing compilation error, is there any other method to define iterator for this ??
my code is

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void dijkstra(vector<vector<pair<long long,long long>>> &ar,long long a,vector<long long> &distance){
    set<pair<long long,long long>> br;
    br.insert(make_pair(a,0));
    distance[a]=0;
    while(!br.empty()){
        set<pair<long long,long long>> :: iterator z=br.begin();  
        long long u=z->first;
        br.erase(z);  
        for(vector<vector<pair<long long,long long> > > :: iterator i=ar[u].begin();i<ar[u].end();i++){
            long long v=i->first;
            long long wt=i->second;
            if(distance[v]>distance[u]+wt){
                if(distance[v]!=100000000){
                    br.erase(br.find(pair<long long,long long>(v,distance[v])));
                }
                distance[v]=distance[u]+wt;
                br.insert(pair<int,int>(v,distance[v]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In many places of your code you wrote ">>>" instead of "> > >", that causes a compilation error. Besides, It could be useful if you add the compilation error in your post.

Comment: `ar` is a `vector<vector<pair>>`. Then `ar[u]` is a `vector<pair>` (one fewer `vector`s), and `ar[u].begin()` is `vector<pair>::iterator`.

Comment: Use some typedefs to make this clearer.   eg `typedef long long BigInt; typedef vector<BigInt> BigVector;`

Comment: Though `auto` would fix the compiler error, I wonder if this is actually an indication of a _logic_ error, since `ar[u]` is not a `vector<vector<pair<long long,long long>>>` but rather merely a `vector<pair<long long,long long>>` (as AlexYang pointed out).

Comment: auto fixed the compilation error but as Igor pointed out its not working, can anyone tell me how to access the real vector ??

Answer (score 0):

one possible error could be you assigned a `vector<pair<long long, long long> >` to `vector<vector<pair<long long,long long> > >` iterator. That will case a compilation error.